# Unable to open SQLite database stored at assets\databases using SQLiteAssetHelper

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-assets

I am trying to use my `SQLite database` from `assets/databases` folder using `SQLiteAssetHelper` class but I am getting following error:-

```
09-25 01:34:53.007: E/SQLiteLog(1191): (14) cannot open file at line 30191 of [00bb9c9ce4]
09-25 01:34:53.007: E/SQLiteLog(1191): (14) os_unix.c:30191: (2) open(/data/data/com.sqlitetospinner1/databases/mydb.sqlite) - 
09-25 01:34:53.067: E/SQLiteDatabase(1191): Failed to open database '/data/data/com.sqlitetospinner1/databases/mydb.sqlite'.
09-25 01:34:53.067: E/SQLiteDatabase(1191): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
09-25 01:34:53.067: E/SQLiteDatabase(1191):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
09-25 01:34:53.067: E/SQLiteDatabase(1191):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
09-25 01:34:53.067: E/SQLiteDatabase(1191):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
09-25 01:34:53.067: E/SQLiteDatabase(1191):     at com.crm.AssetsHelper.getAllColleges(AssetsHelper.java:37)
09-25 01:34:53.067: E/SQLiteDatabase(1191):     at com.crm.Quote_Details.loadSpinnerData(Quote_Details.java:127)
09-25 01:34:53.067: E/SQLiteDatabase(1191):     at com.crm.Quote_Details.onCreate(Quote_Details.java:66)
09-25 01:34:53.067: W/SQLiteAssetHelper(1191): could not open database mydb.sqlite - unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
09-25 01:34:53.077: W/SQLiteAssetHelper(1191): copying database from assets...
09-25 01:34:53.207: E/SQLiteAssetHelper(1191): Couldn't open mydb.sqlite for writing (will try read-only):
09-25 01:34:53.207: E/SQLiteAssetHelper(1191): com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetException: Missing databases/mydb.sqlite.zip file in assets or target folder not writable
09-25 01:34:53.207: E/SQLiteAssetHelper(1191):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
09-25 01:34:53.207: E/SQLiteAssetHelper(1191):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:316)
09-25 01:34:53.207: E/SQLiteAssetHelper(1191):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:290)
09-25 01:34:53.207: E/SQLiteAssetHelper(1191):  at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.copyDatabaseFromAssets(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:376)
09-25 01:34:53.207: E/SQLiteAssetHelper(1191):  at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.createOrOpenDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:355)
09-25 01:34:53.207: E/SQLiteAssetHelper(1191):  at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:178)
09-25 01:34:53.207: E/SQLiteAssetHelper(1191):  at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:257)
09-25 01:34:53.207: E/SQLiteAssetHelper(1191):  at com.crm.AssetsHelper.getAllColleges(AssetsHelper.java:37)
09-25 01:34:53.207: E/SQLiteAssetHelper(1191):  at com.crm.Quote_Details.loadSpinnerData(Quote_Details.java:127)
09-25 01:34:53.207: E/SQLiteAssetHelper(1191):  at com.crm.Quote_Details.onCreate(Quote_Details.java:66)
```

**This is my `AssetHelper` class:-**

```
public class AssetsHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydb.sqlite";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public AssetsHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

public List<String> getAllColleges(){
        List<String> colleges = new ArrayList<String>();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM colleges_list ORDER BY Organization_Name";

    // Below is line number 37
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase(); //Error comes from this line
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                colleges.add(cursor.getString(1));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        return colleges;
    }
}
```

I have already given these permissions in `manifest`:-

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**I have also went through lot of SO questions but none of them were helpful in my case.**

### *UPDATE:-* It used to work earlier but after I changed my db file with another db it stopped working.

Comment: Error : *Missing databases/mydb.sqlite.zip file in assets or target folder not writable* Check it in assets folder and compare names.

Comment: @SilentKiller my db file is there with same name and I am running my code on emulator

Comment: whats name of database in assets folder ?

Comment: @SilentKiller mydb.sqlite

Comment: your exception says you are changing name while fetching database from assets folder. upload code where you copy assets folder DB to device.   *Missing databases/mydb.sqlite.zip file in assets or target folder not writable*

Comment: @SilentKiller copying part is being done by `SQLiteAssetHelper` `jar` file. I am just fetching some data from the copied database to a spinner.

Comment: According to error it says you are coping/accessing db names as *mydb.sqlite.zip* check that

Comment: @SilentKiller yes, I have posted my `AssetHelper` class which is doing this part.

Comment: Please confirm the file is in `assets/databases` and not just assets.

Comment: @laalto it is in assets/databases.

Comment: The logcat tells that the asset file couldn't be opened as `databases/mydb.sqlite`, `databases/mydb.sqlite.zip` or `databases/mydb.sqlite.gz`. The line numbers are different from those in https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper - consider updating the library. Also: which build tooling you're using (Gradle/Android Studio or ADT/Eclipse) and where in the project do you have the assets folder?

Comment: @laalto Downloaded `SQLiteAssetHelper jar` file from [here.](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadandroidsqliteassethelperjar.htm) I am using `ADT(Eclipse)` and my `assets` folder is at **workspace\MyProjectFolder\assets**. Inside `assets` folder there is `databases` folder which contains `mydb.sqlite`.

Comment: There's a much newer jar linked from the github page: http://repository.sonatype.org/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=central-proxy&g=com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset&a=sqliteassethelper&v=LATEST&&c=jar

Comment: @laalto looks like earlier `jar` file was having some problem :) Thank you again Sir. You can post it as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the diagnosis in comments, you're using an ancient version of the asset helper library and that is causing the problems.

The [latest jar](http://repository.sonatype.org/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=central-proxy&g=com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset&a=sqliteassethelper&v=LATEST&&c=jar) is linked on the project's [github page](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper).

Comment: the link asks for some Sonatype Nexus repository Username and Password.. Why?

Answer (score 1):

You need to place your database in assets/databases folder.
SQLiteAssetHelper expects to find the prepopulated database file in databases folder under assets.

[image]

so the placement of the SQLite will be like this

```
assets/  
   databases/  
      mydb.sqlite
```

And after it rebuild and reinstall the app and make sure the placement is right.

Comment: @user1 from the first time? did you already tried to rebuild, uninstall the app and then install it again?

Comment: yes from the first time only. I tried them but didn't helped.

Comment: @user1 how about the databases folder permission? and then the mydb.sqlite permission?